# How to send ether to contract's address?

Tags: solidity, contract-design

I have a problem with sending ether to my contract address via metamask. I found that the function has to be with 'payable' modifier, but it doesn't help. I send transaction, spend ethers from my account, but the contract's address still has 0 value. For example the contract looks like:

```
contract Mycontract
{
  function Mycontract() payable{}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the constructor `Mycontract()` gets called only once.

After that you need to be calling a particular function. Without specifying a particular function, the invocation defaults to the `default function` which is not present in your example. Every smart contract has a `default function` that does nothing and is **not** payable. Because of this, your contract simply refuses to accept the ether.

If you want your contract to do absolutely nothing but accept ether (which would be a silly because you could never get the ether back), you can do this:

```
contract C {
    function C() {}
    function () payable {}
}
```

This will accept ether, but it will be stuck there forever. The second function is the syntax for a `default function`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little hint that might help.

```
contract Mycontract {

  // This is the constructor. It's payable so you can initialize the contract with funds during deploy.
  function Mycontract() payable {}

  // This function is available after deploy. You can send funds to this function. 
  function pay() payable {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`function Mycontract() payable{}` is the contract constructor. It is only executed when the contract is deployed. Marking it as `payable` means you can attach a certain amount when you create the contract.

If you want to to allow anyone to send Ether to your contract, you need to make your contract's `fallback` method `payable`.

You define it like this:

```
contract Mycontract {
    fallback() external payable { }
}
```

You can find more details about the fallback function in [Solidity's official documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.4/contracts.html#fallback-function).